# UIPageViewController - view doesn't load

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiimageview, uipageviewcontroller

I want to load a UIView as the first page and some UIImageViews after that. The UIImageViews load fine, but the first UIView shows blank.
I designed the UIView in storyboard. It has some UIButtons and few other controls. What am I doing wrong?

I created the project from the default pageController template.

ModelController.m

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // Create the data model.
        /*
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        _pageData = [[dateFormatter monthSymbols] copy];
         */
        NSMutableArray *imageViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        FirstViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];
        firstViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.origin.x,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.origin.y,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width);
        [imageViews addObject:firstViewController];


        for (int i=1; i<=19; i++) {
            UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"picture%i.jpg", i]]];

            imageView.frame = CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.origin.x,[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.origin.y,[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width);
            [imageViews addObject:imageView];
        }
        _pageData = imageViews;
    }
    return self;
}

- (DataViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index storyboard:(UIStoryboard *)storyboard
{   
    // Return the data view controller for the given index.
    if (([self.pageData count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageData count])) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    DataViewController *dataViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DataViewController"];
    dataViewController.dataObject = [self.pageData objectAtIndex:index];
    if(index == 0)
    {
        //[dataViewController addChildViewController:[self.pageData objectAtIndex:index]];
        FirstViewController *firstViewController = [self.pageData objectAtIndex:index];
        [dataViewController.view addSubview:firstViewController.view];
    }
    else
    {
        UIImageView *imageView = [self.pageData objectAtIndex:index];
        [dataViewController.view addSubview:imageView];
    }
    return dataViewController;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to working by adding a xib file for FirstViewController. What ever I design in the xib shows up well. Previously I was designing it in the storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided enough context to be certain, but it appears that what you need to load from the storyboard initially is an instance of `FirstViewController`, not an instance of `UIView`, so you'd need to do something like this instead of what you're currently doing:

```
FirstViewController *firstViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateInitialViewController];

// Note: If you need to adjust the frame of the controller's view, use the screen's
// application frame rather than its bounds.
controller.view.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
```

Also, this seems like a bad idea, since you later fill the rest of the array with instances of `UIImageView`:

```
[imageViews addObject:firstViewController];
```

Why not add the controller's view to the array? Then you could eliminate the conditional logic in your `viewControllerAtIndex:storyboard:` method. Also, it's not clear why you're passing the storyboard in as an argument rather than using the built-in property, or for that matter, what class the code you posted belongs to, and what its relation is to the rest of your app. Maybe you could provide a little more info about that.

Comment: That was a silly mistake I made instead of adding the view I was adding the view controller, I corrected it.

Regarding [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame, my app is landscape  orientation based, so when I use applicationFrame somehow it loads the views in portrait mode

Comment: I am writing it again because it wouldn't let me edit it after 5 mins.


That was a silly mistake I made instead of adding the view I was adding the view controller, I corrected it.

Regarding [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame, my app is landscape  orientation based, but when I use applicationFrame somehow it still loads the views in portrait mode

I created this project using the pageViewController template, and this code is on ModelController.m.

Still I couldn't figure out why it's not showing the controls I added to the view.